# Teleportation of Transversal Hadamard Gate from the $[[8,3,2]]$ to $[[4,2,2]]$ codes

Tags: error-correction, teleportation, logical-gates

I'm trying to understand the circuit from Appendix A of the paper [Fault-Tolerant One-Bit Addition with the Smallest Interesting Colour Code](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.09893.pdf).

[image]

Here the top 3 qubits represent the 3 logical qubits of the $[[8,3,2]]$ color code (i'll call $|\psi\rangle$) and the bottom two are the two logical qubits of the $[[4,2,2]]$ code (I'll call $|\phi\rangle$). The problem being solved here is that there is no transversal Hadamard gate on the $[[8,3,2]]$, but there is on the $[[4,2,2]]$ code. So this circuit projects two qubits from $\psi$ onto $\phi$ using transversal CNOT, performs transversal Hadamard on $\phi$, and then teleports them back to $\psi$.

If anyone can provide a systematic explanation of how this circuit works, especially what the purpose of the logical $X$ measurements $\Pi_X$ and why the measurement controlled $X$ operators are done as they are that would be of great help.

The parts that are already clear to me are that performing Hadamard on the $[[4,2,2]]$ code is transversal (with a trivial swap) and there exist transversal CNOT gates between any two qubits of $\psi$ to $\phi$.

Recommendations for other sources to help understand these teleportation-type circuits would also be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be easier to explain if we start with one qubit being teleported. I'm also going to use [Gottesman-Knill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottesman%E2%80%93Knill_theorem) to do the proofs here, and if you're not familiar with it, you should definitely read Chapters 1-6 of [Daniel Gottesman's book](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2024/cmsc858G/QECCbook-2024-ch1-8.pdf), Chapter 6 deals with Gottesman-Knill, but the rest is just as necessary for people working in QEC.

Let's take a look at a simplified version of the circuit above in stages. First, the teleportation:
[image: One-bit teleportation circuit]

The system begins in a state with one stabilizer (because the bottom qubit is prepared in the zero state) and two logical operators which 'live on' the top qubit:
\begin{equation}
S = \begin{array}{cc}
I & Z \\
\hline
X & I \\
Z & I
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Carrying out the CNot results in
\begin{equation}
S = \begin{array}{cc}
Z & Z \\
\hline
X & X \\
Z & I
\end{array} \sim \begin{array}{cc}
Z & Z \\
\hline
X & X \\
I & Z
\end{array}, 
\end{equation}
then projecting the top qubit into the +1 eigenstate of $X$ gives us
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cc}
X & I \\
\hline
X & X \\
I & Z
\end{array} \sim \begin{array}{cc}
X & I \\
\hline
I & X \\
I & Z
\end{array}. 
\end{equation}
The logical operators now live on the bottom qubit, and the top qubit is in a fixed state, so we've teleported the state from top to bottom with this gadget.

We had to use a different circuit to teleport the state back after the Hadamard, because the transversal CNot between the two code blocks only works if logical qubits of the $\left[\hspace{-2pt}\left[ 8,\, 3,\, 2 \right]\hspace{-2pt}\right]$ code are the control qubits:
[image: Alternative one-bit teleportation circuit]

If you replicate the proof for this circuit, you'll see that the measurement may result in a state stabilized by $-IZ$ instead of $IZ$, so multiplying by the $ZZ$ logical operator would result in $-ZI$ instead of $ZI$ like we're after (this also happens in the first teleportation circuit, but is less important, so I just drew a projector instead of a measurement there). That's the reason the conditional $X$ is there.